# How to get call SID in Twilio iOS app

Tags: ios, twilio

I'm trying Twilio SDK to make VOIP call. Call is successfully established. But I want to calculate time(Duration of call).

I got the duration but it's from when it was connected (I mean it started ranging). But I need during since receiver received the call.

Is there any method or callback or delegate which receive this duration when call ends ?

Or Can I find Call SID in iOS app so that I can make twilio rest api call and get call detail ? Because I'm not able to find sid in callbacks.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472294/how-to-get-outgoing-call-duration-with-twilio-clinet-api-in-android refer this

Comment: twilio delegate method "connectionDidConnect: " called when it's connected as I mentioned, I want time stamp of when call actually received by receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SID: When we use a server to initiate a call, than we get SID on server as callback or return parameter. But there is no direct way like server in iOS to get SID

Now, Call duration,

Nevertheless, you wouldn't use the iOS SDK, but rather, you can get the Call Duration in a request paramter as CallDuration after a call completes by using the StatusCallback - which is outlined here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#asynchronous.

"said by twilio support"

As I was not developing a full server, I just used server for getting token, I used call log Rest api of twilio and with available filters parameter in that rest API it was easy to get last call detail and from there get call duration.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the call sid appears to be accessible by accessing TVOcallinvite callsid property in the 3.0 API